# PyCharm formatting file

Tags: pycharm

Is there a file which I can place in the root of some directory and PyCharm will read the formatting settings (like tab space, indent space, etc.)?

Similar as [`.kateconfig` for Kate](http://kate-editor.org/2006/02/09/kateconfig-files/).

I need this directory based (and automatically inherited for all subdirs) and not per project because the main project will use different formatting settings. But I have a subdir where I need different formatting settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) now. It has a plugin for PyCharm and also supports many other editors which is a huge advantage. It seems to work fine.